# HTML Form - Button to submit empty string or default text

Tags: html, forms

Is it possible to have a button on my HTML template which sends an empty string to the handler? E.g. I used this form which has a text box:

```
<form method="POST" action="/data">
<p>City name: <input type="text" name="city_choice"></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form><br></html>
```

This gives a text box with a submit button, is it possible to just have a submit button which sends either an empty string or some default text?

Answer (score 1):

There are two option, first using input type "hidden" with default text like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/data">
   <input type="hidden" name="city_choice" value="Some default text">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and second using jquery ajax.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the way you were asked for, but instead of using `input` you can use keyword `button`:

```
<form method="POST" action="/data">
    <button type="submit" value="test vlaue is sending" name="submit">CLICK ME</button>
</form>
```

will result in sending `value` from button, whatever you type in, but the button will be visible as `CLICK ME`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried usign hidden html fields? You can set your default text there and send it with a button.

http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms07.htm